# python-telegram-bot Pass argument between conversation handlers

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to write a bot where a user clicks on a command, sends a link as a message, and then the bot adds the link to some database. Here's how it would look:

[image: python-telegram-bot]

So I thought I should use a `ConversationHandler`. Here's what I wrote, the `bot.py`:

```py
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,
        ConversationHandler)
from settings import BOT_TOKEN
import commands

def main():
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    conversation = ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[
                MessageHandler(
                    (Filters.command & Filters.regex("al_(.*)")),
                    commands.add_link
                )
            ],
            states={
                commands.ADD_LINK: [
                    MessageHandler(Filters.entity("url"), commands.receive_link)
                ]
            },
            fallbacks=[]
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("search", commands.search))
    dispatcher.add_handler(conversation)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And commands are in another file called `commands.py`:

```py
from telegram.ext import ConversationHandler

ADD_LINK = range(1)

def receive_link(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    url = update.message.text
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id

    bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text="The link has been added."
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def add_link(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    uuid = update.message.text.replace("/al_", "")
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text="Send the link as a message."
    )

    return ADD_LINK
```

Now the problem is that I need to be able to use the `uuid` variable (that is generated in `add_link`) in my `receive_link` function. But I don't know how to pass this variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of this [article](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data), I solved it like this.

> By using `context.user_data` in any Handler callback, you have access to a user-specific dict.

So my code would change as follows:

```py
from telegram.ext import ConversationHandler

ADD_LINK = range(1)

def receive_link(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    url = update.message.text
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    uuid = context.user_data["uuid"]

    bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text=f"The link has been added to '{uuid}'."
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def add_link(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    uuid = update.message.text.replace("/al_", "")
    context.user_data["uuid"] = uuid
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text=f"Send the link as a message."
    )

    return ADD_LINK
```

I stored the `uuid` variable like this:

```
context.user_data["uuid"] = uuid
```

And use it like this:

```
uuid = context.user_data["uuid"]
```

Pretty easy and intuitive. Here's the output:

[image: python-telegram-bot store user data]